# Entity Framework & VB.Net - How do I Bind Textboxes to EF and Persist Changes?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

In an application I have created, I have a need to load and edit ~150 "settings."  (These settings are weights that are used to score answers given in the main form.)

I have created a "Settings" form which contains a TabControl, several tabs, and a textbox for each setting.  I was able to figure out how to load the textboxes with the appropriate values from EF (albeit maybe the wrong way) but I cannot figure out how to persist changes made to these settings.

I have searched all over the web trying to find anything that talked about binding EF with textboxes.  However, all I can find is binding with DGV, comboboxes, listviews, etc.  I wouldn't think what I'm trying to do is that complicated, but maybe I'm going about it the wrong way?  Also, I'm totally new to EF so I really am not sure what I'm looking for.  I've read several section in books referring to getting data and persisting it, but none of it seems to apply to this situation, or it just didn't make sense to me.

The table that holds the values is simple: Table Name: "tbl_Weights" - Columns: ID_Weight, Weight_Name, Weight_Value

Initially, this is how I populated the textboxes:

(Custom Class to load the values)

```
Public Class Weights
    Public Property Title_TLCP_Yes As Integer
    Public Property Title_TLCP_No As Integer
    Public Property Title_TLCP_NA As Integer
    Public Property Title_NewTest_Yes As Integer
    Public Property Title_NewTest_No As Integer
    Public Property Title_DevTech_Yes As Integer
    Public Property Title_DevTech_No As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        Using dbTPT As New BGL_ApplicationsEntities
            _Title_TLCP_Yes = dbTPT.tbl_Weights.Where(Function(a) a.Weight_Name = "Title_TLCP_Yes").Select(Function(b) b.Weight_Value).FirstOrDefault()
            _Title_TLCP_No = dbTPT.tbl_Weights.Where(Function(a) a.Weight_Name = "Title_TLCP_No").Select(Function(b) b.Weight_Value).FirstOrDefault()
            _Title_TLCP_NA = dbTPT.tbl_Weights.Where(Function(a) a.Weight_Name = "Title_TLCP_NA").Select(Function(b) b.Weight_Value).FirstOrDefault()
            _Title_NewTest_Yes = dbTPT.tbl_Weights.Where(Function(a) a.Weight_Name = "Title_NewTest_Yes").Select(Function(b) b.Weight_Value).FirstOrDefault()
            _Title_NewTest_No = dbTPT.tbl_Weights.Where(Function(a) a.Weight_Name = "Title_NewTest_No").Select(Function(b) b.Weight_Value).FirstOrDefault()
            _Title_DevTech_Yes = dbTPT.tbl_Weights.Where(Function(a) a.Weight_Name = "Title_DevTech_Yes").Select(Function(b) b.Weight_Value).FirstOrDefault()
            _Title_DevTech_No = dbTPT.tbl_Weights.Where(Function(a) a.Weight_Name = "Title_DevTech_No").Select(Function(b) b.Weight_Value).FirstOrDefault()
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

And then using the following to populate the results:

```
Dim WeightSettings As New Weights
txtT_TLCP_Yes.Text = WeightSettings.Title_TLCP_Yes
txtT_TLCP_No.Text = WeightSettings.Title_TLCP_No
txtT_TLCP_NA.Text = WeightSettings.Title_TLCP_NA
txtT_NewTest_Yes.Text = WeightSettings.Title_NewTest_Yes
txtT_NewTest_No.Text = WeightSettings.Title_NewTest_No
txtT_DevTech_Yes.Text = WeightSettings.Title_DevTech_Yes
txtT_DevTech_No.Text = WeightSettings.Title_DevTech_No
```

I have also tried using a BindingSource to see if that would persist changes; but as you can guess, no, it did not.

```
Dim WeightSettings As New Weights
Dim bs As New BindingSource
bs.DataSource = WeightSettings

txtT_TLCP_Yes.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Title_TLCP_Yes")
txtT_TLCP_No.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Title_TLCP_No")
txtT_TLCP_NA.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Title_TLCP_NA")
txtT_NewTest_Yes.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Title_NewTest_Yes")
txtT_NewTest_No.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Title_NewTest_No")
txtT_DevTech_Yes.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Title_DevTech_Yes")
txtT_DevTech_No.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "Title_DevTech_No")
```

If anyone has any ideas how I can do this, the appropriate way, and/or explain what I need to research to find the answer, that would be great.

Also, if anyone has any sources that explain EF in a VB.Net context, that would also be appreciated.  While I can "read" C#, it makes it difficult learning something when I am constantly trying to decode another language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exactly databinding, but it can help you automate the loading and setting of all your textboxes. The code inside Form_Load basically does all of that in a small amount of code.

```vb
Public Class Form1

    Private weightSettings As Weights

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        weightSettings = New Weights()
        For Each tb As TextBox In Me.ChildControls(Of TextBox).Where(Function(t) t.Name.Contains("txtT_"))
            Dim propertyName = tb.Name.Replace("txtT", "Title")
            Dim pi = GetType(Weights).GetProperty(propertyName)
            tb.Text = CType(pi.GetValue(weightSettings), Integer).ToString()
            AddHandler tb.Validated,
                Sub()
                    Dim value = Integer.Parse(tb.Text)
                    pi.SetValue(weightSettings, value)
                    Using dbTPT As New BGL_ApplicationsEntities
                        Dim w = dbTPT.tbl_Weights.FirstOrDefault(Function(n) n.WeightName = propertyName)
                        If w IsNot Nothing Then
                            w.Weight_Value = value
                            dbTPT.SaveChanges()
                        End If
                    End Using
                End Sub
        Next
    End Sub
End Class

Module extensions
    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
    Public Function ChildControls(Of TControl As Control)(parent As Control) As IEnumerable(Of TControl)
        Dim result As New List(Of TControl)
        For Each ctrl As Control In parent.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is TControl Then result.Add(CType(ctrl, TControl))
            result.AddRange(ctrl.ChildControls(Of TControl)())
        Next
        Return result
    End Function
End Module

Public Class Weights
    Public Property Title_TLCP_Yes As Integer
    Public Property Title_TLCP_No As Integer
    Public Property Title_TLCP_NA As Integer
    Public Property Title_NewTest_Yes As Integer
    Public Property Title_NewTest_No As Integer
    Public Property Title_DevTech_Yes As Integer
    Public Property Title_DevTech_No As Integer

    Public Sub New()
        Using dbTPT As New BGL_ApplicationsEntities
            For Each pi In Me.GetType().GetProperties(Reflection.BindingFlags.Public Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).Where(Function(p) p.Name.Contains("Title_"))
                Dim w = dbTPT.tbl_Weights.FirstOrDefault(Function(a) a.Weight_Name = pi.Name)
                If w IsNot Nothing Then pi.SetValue(Me, w.Select(Function(b) b.Weight_Value))
            Next
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

This assumes all the properties in Weights are Integers (this is what you provided in the abridged version).

This greatly simplifies the following parts of your question:

> (Custom Class to load the values)

From ~150 lines of hard-coded settings, to a few future-proof lines

> And then using the following to populate the results

From ~150 lines of hard-coded settings, to a few future-proof lines

The key is using `Reflection` to find properties by property name. And an extension method to find all TextBoxes matching a filter (`Me.Controls` works when they are all in `Me`, and not in a container such as you noted). A dynamic added event handler triggers when each TextBox is validated, and will update your database based on the TextBox name.

You could also have the Weights class hold a Dictionary(Of String, Integer) acting as lookup from weight name to weight value. This would further simplify your code, and it would be easier to get the weights out by key instead of reflection. But it's up to you.

Addressing your questions:

Code with a dictionary. Adds all weights to your class. You could restrict which ones with a LINQ Where in the query

```vb
Public Class Weights

    Public ReadOnly Property Items As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()

    Public Sub New()
        Using dbTPT As New BGL_ApplicationsEntities
            Dim weights = From w In dbTPT.tbl_Weights Select w
            For Each weight In weights
                Items.Add(weight.Weight_Name, weight.Weight_Value)
            Next
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: So I started with looking through your code and comments and thought about it for a bit.  I think you are correct that it would be easier to use a Dictionary(Of String, Integer) to hold names and values.  However, there are a couple issues I need some help working through.  1) What would that class look like with the Dictionary? 2) I should have added a mix of property examples - they don't all start with "Title_" - so some of your code I corrected to adjust for this.  I did go ahead and add the TextBox name to the database, so I could pull that with the Weight Name and Value.

Comment: I started adding the dictionary, but I'm not sure how to set the value per your origianal code. Obviously the following is not going to work: `pi.SetValue(Me, w.Weight_Name, Weight_Value)`

Comment: @Cory Are your TextBoxes arranged in a deliberate way, or would it be possible for the code to generate them in a vertical list or FlowLayoutPanel for instance?

Comment: @Cory added a Weights class with dictionary to the answer

Comment: Not sure what you mean by how the TextBoxes are arranged.  If you mean by arranged in the form, then they are arranged in separate TabControl tabs for ease-of-use.  I see what you did with the class... I was thinking more like `Public Property Title_TLCP_Yes As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)` to store the TextBox name and Weight_Value.  I'll need an "easier" way to link TextBoxes to their Weight Value since they are not all named the same.  i.e. Title_TLCP_Yes = txtT_TLCP_Yes,  Academic_PubMethod_Yes = txtA_PubMethod_Yes.  I suppose I could rename them to be txtPropertyName?

Comment: @Cory If you are able to bidirectionally go between textbox name and weight name that's all that matters. Perhaps you have standardized the names such as txt<FirstLetterOfPrefix>_Suffix, what I mean by prefix is T:Title, A:Academic, etc. then you can with little effort go between textbox name and weight name.

Comment: @Cory and how they are arranged, it's possible to dynamically generate your textboxes at runtime without manually placing one on the form ever. Then you can name them whatever (i.e. just name it `txt_<weightName>`) and simplify it further

Comment: I was able to get everything completed with the code you provided.  However, I did go ahead and rename all the textboxes to be txt<Weight_Name>.  Although the TextBoxes were standardized with txt<FirstLetterOfPrefix>_Suffix, I was not sure how to go about that, so I stuck with what I know.  I will have to explore dynamically adding controls in the future - it sounds handy, but I have never done it.  Thank you for your solution and help!!!